# Unable to install php-intl extension on ubuntu 19.10 with php 7.3

Tags: php, ubuntu-19.10

Tried many possible solutions on stackoverflow but unable to install php intl extension for php7.3 on ubuntu 19.10.

Getting below errors while tying to install php intl.

```
Ign:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/universe amd64 php7.3-intl amd64 7.3.11-0ubuntu0.19.10.6
Ign:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe amd64 php-intl all 2:7.3+69ubuntu2
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan/universe amd64 php-intl all 2:7.3+69ubuntu2 404  Not Found
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates/universe amd64 php7.3-intl amd64 7.3.11-0ubuntu0.19.10.6 404  Not Found 
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php7.3/php7.3-intl_7.3.11-0ubuntu0.19.10.6_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/php-defaults/php-intl_7.3+69ubuntu2_all.deb  404  Not Found
```

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/eoan/+package/php-intl. Package shows no data available for php-intl.

Comment: run `apt update` before `apt install`

Comment: Your ubuntu install cant connect to the repo to download anything. Most likely because of an internet issue.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 is also no longer supports, you should upgrade asap. https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2020-July/000258.html

Comment: kadhi nakh ubuntu ne ghare giya kar

Comment: That does not look like a programming-related question. What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php-intl
sudo apt-get install php-xsl
```

you can specific install version as such 7.3

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-intl
sudo apt-get install php7.3-xsl
```

if you using apache

```
sudo php5enmod xsl
sudo service apache2 restart
```

if you using `php-fpm` restart `php-fpm`  ,or restart  `nginx`

**dont forget to restart PHP service or HTTP service**

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be:

**Add Repository**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -y install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
```

**Install PHP 7.3**

`sudo apt install -y php7.4`

**Install Modules**

```
apt install php7.3 php7.3-cli php7.3-cgi php7.3-fpm php7.3-gd php7.3-mysql php7.3-imap php7.4-curl php7.3-intl php7.3-pspell php7.3-sqlite3 php7.3-tidy php7.3-xmlrpc php7.3-xsl php7.3-zip php7.3-mbstring php7.3-soap php7.3-opcache libonig5 php7.3-common php7.3-json php7.3-readline php7.3-xml
```

**If you need  fpm**
apt install php7.3-fpm